# setInputValue won't actually change the input value in ant design component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am using this component from Ant Design:

```
<InputNumber min={1} max={10} value={value} onChange={setValue} />
```

[Component here](https://codepen.io/pen?&editors=001)

Basically, what I am interested in is onChange event. Expected onChange behavior: if the number of decimals is greater than 5 - truncate number to 5 decimals. Basically 1,1234567 becomes 1,12345. With this code I am able to reach the truncation of the inputValue:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string | number | null>(null);
  
  const handleChange: CustomOnChange = (value) => {
    // Get the raw input value from the event object
    const rawInputValue = value === null ? '' : value.toString();

    // Check if the raw input value has more than 5 decimals
    const decimalCount = rawInputValue.split('.')[1]?.length || 0;

    if (decimalCount > 5) {
      const numberValue = Number(value);
      const decimalPlaces = 5;
      const factor = 10 ** decimalPlaces;
      const truncatedNumber = Math.trunc(numberValue * factor) / factor;
      console.log(truncatedNumber)
      setInputValue(truncatedNumber);
      
    }
    console.log(inputValue)
  };
```

Any time I type into input more than 5 decimals and log my inputValue - it stays 1,12345 as in the example above.

However, in the UI, in my input field I am able to type further, adding an endless amount of decimals. I tried out precision and it also didn't work. The effect of text input known as maxlength should take place: user should basically have the feeling, he/she can'T type further, after reaching 5 decimals.